# Using Ajax to access Ruby HTTP server

Tags: ruby, jquery, httpserver

I wrote a very simple HTTP server at my PC by ruby. I can access the it from IE/FF/Chrome and display the result XML correctly, however when I tried to access it by a Jquery AJAX call, looks like it only got the header of the response. Anyone can help?

the code of ruby

```
 server = TCPServer.new('localhost',  9000)
  loop {
  client = server.accept()
  while((x = client.gets) != "\r\n")
    puts x
  end

  $result= "<root><data>123</data></root>"
  headers = ["HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
             "Date: Tue, 14 Dec 2010 10:48:45 GMT",
             "Server: Ruby",
             "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=gb2312",
             "Content-Length: #{$result.bytesize}\r\n\r\n"].join("\r\n")
client.puts headers
client.puts $result

  client.close
  puts "Request Handled"
```

and the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost:9000",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"xml",
                        async:true,
                    timeout: 2000,
                    error: function(xml, status, err){
                        alert('Error loading XML document'+xml+status+err);
                    },
                    success: function(xml){
                        $(xml).find("data").each(function(i){
                                alert($(this).text());

                        });
                    }
                });

        });

});
```

ok, I got the reason. AJAX should only access the URL in the same domain. I put the AJAX code in a local HTML, hence can't access the server.

updated server code as below, and put the AJAX html under "/", the access point it "http:/ /localhost  : 9000/ajax.html"

```
require 'webrick'

$mydata="<root><data>test1</data><data>test2</data></root>"
class MyServlet < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
  def do_GET(request, response)
    response.status = 200
    response.content_type = "text/xml"
    response.body = $mydata
  end
end

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 9000,:DocumentRoot=>Dir::pwd)
server.mount "/data", MyServlet
trap("INT"){ server.shutdown }
server.start
```

Comment: Please include the results when you make a standard call and when you make an AJAX call.

Comment: You should answer your own question and select it as best answer instead edit the body of your question.